# sending mail with php mail() in plesk control panel

Tags: php, email, plesk

This is my code:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['send']) ) {
$name = $_POST['name'];

$to = 'kiarash@gmail.com';  
$subject = 'Test Sending';
$message = 'This is Test    for sending Mail';
$header = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . "\r\n" .
                    'From: test@site.ir' . "\r\n" .
                    'Replt-To: test@site.ir' . "\r\n";

$mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
echo "this is mail sent---> " . $mailsent;
}
?>
```

and this HTML code:

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="frm">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" />
</form>
```

My host is on Parallel Plesk... But the mail did not send to...

What's my problem? Have You any Idea or Suggestion For me?

this is full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['send']) ) {
$name = $_POST['name'];

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);



$to = 'kiarash@gmail.com';  
$subject = 'Test Sending';
$message = 'This is Test    for sending Mail';
$header = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . "\r\n" .
                    'From: info@site.ir' . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: info@site.ir' . "\r\n";

$mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

if($mailsent){
echo "success";
}else{
echo "not sent";
}
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post" name="frm">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked SPAM?

Comment: what do you get on echo?($mailsent) is it 0 or 1

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha There is noting, Just The String text that I did write with echo!!!

Comment: I am using a page with XHTML DOCTYPE...
May be it's the problem!!! what do you think?

Comment: `Replt-To` looks like a typo. But in general if you're sending mail via PHP, I strongly suggest using a decent mailer library like PHPMailer of SwiftMailer; using PHP's built-in `mail()` function is always going to give you problems; it's very difficult to work with.

Comment: @Spudley I fixed Reply-To, But the problem didn't solve..
You mean work with PHPMailer is easier than mail()???
I don't know any thing about this framework, can I learn it in a few hours?

Comment: @Kiyarash - yes, PHPMailer is *extremely* easy to use. It's a lot easier than writing your own headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, your headers are funky. Tested this and it works.

```
<?php
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $from = "info@site.ir";
        $to = 'kiarash@gmail.com';  
        $subject = 'Test Sending';
        $message = 'You got a message from '. $name;
        $headers = array(
            'MIME-Version: 1.0',
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
            'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from
        );
        $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\n", $headers));
        if($mailsent){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "not sent";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="frm">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I Updated the Question with full page code...
Take a look please.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it in a page without any changes but still the answer is (( not sent ))!!! I'm really confused

Comment: @Kiyarash - Are you running on localhost or on a live server? if localhost, you need to have a mailserver installed. if live server create a new document and put `<?php echo php_info(); ?>` and run it. paste the contents somewhere and link to it.

Comment: I'm in live server with plesk control panel. Dear Adelphia, I download PHPMailer and work for a while on this framework and finally I could send a mail with server... I appreciate your attention...

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

At the top of your PHP code.

Also, replace

```
echo "this is mail sent---> " . $mailsent;
```

with

```
if($mailsent){
echo "success";
}else{
echo "not sent";
}
```

because `$mailsent` is not a string you shouldn't try and echo it.

It may also help to make a `php_info()` file and check the mail parameters.

Comment: I Used your suggestion but there is noting to show, error_reporting didn't work, and the answer of if condition was ( Not Sent )!

and this is from error log in my Host about PHP_INFO()

[Thu Sep 26 09:40:55 2013] [warn] [client 1.111.11.111] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function php_info() in /var/www/vhosts/site.ir/httpdocs/index.php on line 30, referer: http://site.ir/